# javascriptEnabled issue on Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I was using phantomjs to scrape some data from a website. In order to speed up the loading I disabled the execution of js on the webpage by doing this:

```
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;
```

but this causes the problem--it makes `page.evaluate(somefunc.toString())` return `null` no matter what the function should return.
If I keep the js setting default to true the `page.evaluate()` would work again.

How should I work around this?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a better answer here than "Don't do that"? If you don't enable JS, the page can't evaluate a JS function. (Also, you can pass a function reference to `page.evaluate()` - the `.toString()` is unnecessary.)

Comment: I have to agree with narbinowitz on this. If you turn off JS on a page, it will certainly not be able to evaluate JS within the context of the page.

Comment: I have to disagree with that, phantomJS is supposed to work as the browser would. While disabling javascript on Chrome, for example, you still have access to the console within developer tools and consequently the `window` object. I believe it should mimic the same behaviour, where disabling javascript means phantomjs should only disable scripts for running within the page, but not prevent the developer to evaluate new ones. through the console, where, on phantomjs `evaluate` is the only way to go.

Comment: I agree with zanona, not being able to run javascript against pages with javascript disabled basically means you can't inspect them at all. I'm obviously ignoring the effort it would take to implement the feature but I can't think of any practical reason why you would want to prevent javascript from being used to inspect the page after it's been rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, don't do that.

However, if you *really* need that, you may keep JavaScript enabled, but block loading external *.js* files. E.g.:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
  if (requestData['Content-Type'] == 'application/javascript' || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/javascript') {
    console.log('Disabling JavaScript files. Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);
    request.abort();
  }
};
```